# WRDS Python package error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn

Tags: python, psycopg2, wrds-compusat

According to WRDS (large data provider) itself, one can list the different libraries of data they provide by doing the following ([source](https://wrds-www.wharton.upenn.edu/documents/1443/wrds_connection.html)):

```
import wrds

db = wrds.Connection()

db.list_libraries()
```

This works fine for me. One can then look at all the different tables in a library by doing the following:

```
db.list_tables(library='comp')
```

where "comp", is an examplatory library.

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column c.relnamespace does not exist
LINE 1: ...me FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnames...
                                                             ^

[SQL: SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE n.nspname = %(schema)s AND c.relkind IN ('v', 'm')]
[parameters: {'schema': 'comp'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

What is my mistake here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Postgresql are you using?

Comment: @snakecharmerb the only package I am working with is the wrds one. So I am not aware of that. I guess postgresql is part of the wrds package? If so - how do I check which version I am using?

Comment: Oh I see, the server is remote.  What's the result of `db.raw_sql("SELECT version()")`?

Comment: The result is: version
0  PostgreSQL 12.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compil...

Comment: Hmmm.  I can see that column definitely exists in 12.4.  Does it show in the output of  `db.raw_sql("\d pg_class")`?

Comment: It gives me the following: `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \d pg_class
        ^

[SQL: \d pg_class]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)`

Comment: I think the best thing to do is raise a support ticket with the WRDS people (there's a link on their site).  `relnamespace` certainly exists in older and later versions of Postgresql, so perhaps there's a problem with your account setup.

Comment: @snakecharmerb WRDS appeared to have problems - it was not any fault on my side. They fixed it now - thanks.